# When would you use an std::auto_ptr instead of boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, shared-ptr, auto-ptr

We've pretty much moved over to using `boost::shared_ptr` in all of our code, however we still have some isolated cases where we use `std::auto_ptr`, including singleton classes:

```
template < typename TYPE >
class SharedSingleton
{
public: 
    static TYPE& Instance()
    {
        if (_ptrInstance.get() == NULL)
            _ptrInstance.reset(new TYPE);
        return *_ptrInstance;
    }

protected: 
    SharedSingleton() {};

private:
    static std::auto_ptr < TYPE > _ptrInstance;
};
```

I've been told that there's a very good reason why this hasn't been made a `shared_ptr`, but for the life of me I can't understand why?  I know that `auto_ptr` will eventually get marked as depreciated in the next standard, so I'd like to **know what/how I can replace this implementation**.

**Also, are there any other reasons why you'd consider using an `auto_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`?** And do you see any problems moving to shared_ptr in the future?

---

**Edit:**

1. So in answer to "can I safely replace `auto_ptr` with `shared_ptr` in the above code", the answer is yes - however I'll take a small performance hit.
2. When `auto_ptr` is eventually marked as depreciated and we move over to `std::shared_ptr`, we'll need to thoroughly test our code to make sure we're abiding by the different ownership semantics.

Comment: auto_ptr is getting *replaced*, mostly because of how it deals with move semantics, as maintaining backwards compatibility is cleaner than updating it, in this case.  The new class should *\*crosses fingers\** be almost a drop-in replacement, though.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`auto_ptr` and `shared_ptr` solve entirely different problems. One does not replace the other.

`auto_ptr` is a thin wrapper around pointers to implement [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) semantics, so that resources are always released, even when facing exceptions. `auto_ptr` does not perform any reference counting or the like at all, it does not make multiple pointers point to the same object when creating copies. In fact, it's very different. `auto_ptr` is one of the few classes where the assignment operator modifies the **source** object. Consider this shameless plug from the [auto_ptr wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr):

```
int *i = new int;
auto_ptr<int> x(i);
auto_ptr<int> y;

y = x;

cout << x.get() << endl; // Print NULL
cout << y.get() << endl; // Print non-NULL address i
```

Note how executing

```
y = x;
```

modifies not only y but also x.

The `boost::shared_ptr` template makes it easy to handle multiple pointers to the same object, and the object is only deleted after the last reference to it went out of scope. This feature is not useful in your scenario, which (attempts to) implement a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). In your scenario, there's always either 0 references to 1 reference to the only object of the class, if any.

In essence, `auto_ptr` objects and `shared_ptr` objects have entirely different semantics (that's why you cannot use the former in containers, but doing so with the latter is fine), and I sure hope you have good tests to catch any regressions you introduced while porting your code. :-}

Answer (score 14):

Others have answered why this code uses an `auto_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`.  To address your other questions:

*What/how I can replace this implementation?*

Use either `boost::scoped_ptr` or `unique_ptr` (available in both Boost and the new C++ standard).  Both `scoped_ptr` and `unique_ptr` provide strict ownership (and no reference counting overhead), andthey avoid the surprising delete-on-copy semantics of `auto_ptr`.

*Also, are there any other reasons why you'd consider using an `auto_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`?  And do you see any problems moving to `shared_ptr` in the future?*

Personally, I would not use an `auto_ptr`.  Delete-on-copy is just too non-intuitive.  [Herb Sutter seems to agree](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401839).  Switching to `scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, or `shared_ptr` should offer no problems.  Specifically, `shared_ptr` should be a drop-in replacement if you don't care about the reference counting overhead.  `scoped_ptr` is a drop-in replacement if you aren't using `auto_ptr`'s transfer-of-ownership capabilities.  If you are using transfer-of-ownership, then `unique_ptr` is almost a drop-in replacement, except that you need to instead explicitly call `move` to transfer ownership.  See [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=400) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

auto_ptr is the only kind of smart pointer I use. I use it because I don't use Boost, and because I generally prefer my business/application-oriented classes to explicitly 
define deletion semantics and order, rather than depend on 
collections of, or individual, smart pointers.

Comment: Smart pointers are useful tools for writing safe and efficient code in C++.  It is very hard to write exception neutral, memory leak free programs without them.

Comment: auto_ptr (which I've already said I use) IS a  smart pointer!

Comment: Well auto_ptr is not that smart ;-)  You can't handle shared resources with it.  So you probably have written, or should have, your own ref counted pointer for that and that is exactly what shared_ptr is doing for you. I find it very bad advice not to use any smart pointer except auto_ptr.  I would advice exactly the opposite because auto_ptr has been given two responsibilities: ensuring that it is properly destroyed no matter how we leave the scope and to safely transfer objects from one location to another. shared_ptr or unique_ptr should be used instead.

Comment: I don't believe in shared resources. A resource should belong to one instance of one class. And I didn't give the advice to not use any other kind of smart pointer - I described what I do.

Comment: And what about cross cutting concerns, context objects, shared data, optimization strategies, hardware interfaces, ... - Isn't describing what you do and giving advice the same :S